# Need help to understand the below recursive function code

Tags: python, function, recursion

help us to understand the logic of the following code in Python(recursive function):

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k > 0):
    result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)
```

Output:

```
Recursion Example Results
1
3
6
10
15
21
```

When I try to understand the logic of this program and try to predict the output I don't get the output I get only the print line output as "Recursion Example Results", but when I compile and execute it, the output comes like which I given above.

Comment: *"I get only the print line output as "Recursion Example Results"* Why are you ignoring `print(result)`? Perhaps start with a smaller `k` value.

Comment: `print(result)` will be printed for each recursion call except the last. Why do you expect something different?

Comment: Can you explain why you think it shouldn't output anything else? 6 is greater than 0, so `k > 0` will be true at least once, meaning at least one print() statement will be reached...